# Close Kendo Angular Dialog using child component button click

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a form component that I embed in a dialog using the kendo dialog service. I'm able to call my service and save my form data on my save click. I'm trying to figure out how to close the dialog after the save click. I want to keep all of logic in the dialog component and just open the dialog from the parent component. Validation and saving call will happen in the dialog component. I could just use a template and place the save/close functions in the parent component but I want to isolate this to the child component used by the dialog service.

ClientComponent.ts

```
    import { AddClientComponent } from './add-client.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../services/client.service';
import { DialogService, DialogCloseResult, DialogRef } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';

@Component({
    selector: 'clients',
    templateUrl: 'ClientComponent.html',
    styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
    moduleId: module.id
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {
    public clients: any[];
    private title = 'Clients';

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService, private dialogService: DialogService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.clients = this.clientService.getClients();
    }

    public showAddClient() {
        const dialog: DialogRef  = this.dialogService.open({
            title: "Add User",

            // show component
            content: AddClientComponent
        });

        dialog.result.subscribe((result) => {
            if (result instanceof DialogCloseResult) {
                console.log("close");
            } else {
                console.log("action", result);
                this.clients = this.clientService.getClients();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

clientComponent.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<br/>

<button (click)="showAddClient(dialogActions)" class="k-button">Add Client</button>

<kendo-grid [data]="clients">
    <kendo-grid-column field="Id" title="Id">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="FirstName" title="FirstName">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="LastName" title="LastName">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="DateOfBirth" title="DateOfBirth">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Location" title="Location">
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>

<div kendoDialogContainer></div>
```

add-client.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../services/client.service';
import { Client } from '../entities/Client';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-client',
  templateUrl: 'AddClient.html',
  moduleId: module.id
})
export class AddClientComponent {

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {

    }

    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public dateOfBirth: Date;
    public address: string;

    public Save() {

        var client = new Client(0, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth, this.address)
        this.clientService.addClient(client);
    }
}
```

AddClient.html

```
<form class="k-form">
    <label class="k-form-field">
        <span>First Name</span>
        <input class="k-textbox" placeholder="Your Name" [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstName" />
    </label>
    <label class="k-form-field">
        <span>Last Name</span>
        <input class="k-textbox" placeholder="Your Last Name" [(ngModel)]="lastName" name="lastName" />
    </label>
    <label class="k-form-field">
        <span>Date of Birth</span>
        <kendo-datepicker name="birthDate"
                          [(ngModel)]="birthDate"></kendo-datepicker>
    </label>
    <label class="k-form-field">
        <span>Location</span>
        <input class="k-textbox" placeholder="Perrysburg" [(ngModel)]="location" name="location" />
    </label>

    <button class="k-button pull-right" (click)="Save()" primary="true" style="background-color:deepskyblue">Save</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: are you available in teamviewer so that I can debug?

Comment: sorry I am not @Aravind

Comment: update the `add.client.html` files to post

Comment: @Aravind added.

Comment: sorry please update the other html file as well

Comment: @Aravind added.

Comment: where is the `kendo-dialog` placed? I could not see in both the HTML files

Comment: i could do someting like this post but that seems like a hack. I want to validate my form. Once the form saves, the parent can close the child dialog. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913156/how-to-add-callbacks-to-kendo-dialog-actions?rq=1

Comment: the dialog has a selector in the ClientComponent.html file at the bottom

Comment: @JustinW can you find any solution beacuse i face same issue.

Comment: @bipinpatel I went with a ViewChild for now. The view child handles saving my form then closes. The parent opens the child and passes an object to reset the form. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

There is a better and easier way to do this now. You can check the documentation

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/dialog/service/

Basically all you have to do is to provide a constructor Parameter of the DialogRef type in the child component.

add-client.component.ts would look like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../services/client.service';
import { Client } from '../entities/Client';
import { DialogRef } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';

@Component({
    selector: 'add-client',
    templateUrl: 'AddClient.html',
    moduleId: module.id
}) 

export class AddClientComponent {

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService,
    public dialog : DialogRef) {

    }

    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public dateOfBirth: Date;
    public address: string;

    public Save() {

        var client = new Client(0, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth, this.address)
        this.clientService.addClient(client);
        this.dialog.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check out my answer here to a similar question on preventing the dialog from closing after pressing an action button

[how to add callbacks to kendo dialog actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913156/how-to-add-callbacks-to-kendo-dialog-actions/45791326#45791326)

You can then call functions on your dialog instance directly before closing it so you can keep all the logic inside your dialog component.